# Call subclass method from a superclass method?

Tags: java, overriding, subclass, superclass, extends

My app has a structure similar to this:

```
class Father{
a(){ ... }

b(){a();}
}

class Son extends Father{
a(){ ..... }} //override
```

b() is not overrided.
When I create an instance of Son and I call b(), Father's a() is called, but I would like it executes the Son one (if the object is a Son). Is it possible?

Comment: son's a() should be called in this situation.

Comment: @Hovercraft, I assume the OP means that b() is not overridden, and he wants b() to call Son's a() if the object is a Son

Comment: @SamDeHaan: b **doesn't have to be overridden**

Comment: This is a pretty common design pattern, son's a() should be called assuming you're correctly overriding the a() method.

Comment: @Hovercraft, Ah, well - my bad. Apparently I've been out of Java longer than I thought >.>

Comment: I understood that you called Son.a and that one would call b(). I am too tired and gove it a break :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Son's `a` method should be called.  If it's not, then you're either not operating on an instance of `Son` or you haven't correctly overridden the method.  This could happen if the signatures aren't exactly the same.  I would double check in your implementation that the signatures are exactly the same.  Also, try throwing an `@Override` above the `Son` implementation of `a` and see if you get a compile error.  If you do, then you aren't overriding the method correctly.

Like this

```
class Son extends Father{
  @Override
  a(){ ...}
}
```

Also, `a` must be either protected or public (package private, the default, will only work if `Father` and `Son` are in the same package).  i.e. `Son` must be able to "see" the `a()` method.

Answer (score 5):

No/Yes

- No: "When I create an instance of Son and I call b(), Father's a() is called," That is wrong!
- Yes: "but I would like it executes the Son one (if the object is a Son). Is it possible?" -- That is the behavior of Java

If `a` is not a static method, then java use [dynamic binding](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding-in.html), so the son's `a()` method is called.

`new Son().b()` will invoke the method `a()` in Son.  That is called dynamic binding.

Answer (score -1):

What you have should be correct. Method calls are binded lazily. This means that when you call the method `a()` anywhere in a `Son` object, it will be `Son`'s method that will be called.

Answer (score -1):

Overridden methods are resolved at runtime whereas overloaded methods are resolved at compile time. Hence just invoking new Son().a() should be enough.